# Can't get rows that have same code type and same ZPLID and feature key have both Null and values?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, count, sql-server-2012

I work with SQL Server 2012. I can't get rows from table `#gen` when they have rows with at least one NULL and at least on non-NULL value in the feature key column, based on `Zplid` and `CodeTypeId`.

Meaning I need to get rows that have NULL in the feature key and values in the feature key but must be same `CodeTypeId` and same `Zplid`.

```
create table #gen
(
    CodeTypeId int,
    Zplid  int,
    Zfeaturekey nvarchar(50)
)

insert into #gen 
values (854838, 25820, NULL),
       (849774, 25820, 1502260001),
       (849774, 25820, 1502260001),
       (849774, 25820, 1502260016),
       (849774, 25820, NULL),
       (987431, 26777, 1502270003),
       (987431, 26777, 1502280005),
       (987431, 26777, 1502290001)
```

This is the result I need :

```
 CodeTypeId    Zplid    Zfeaturekey
 ------------------------------------
     849774    25820    1502260001
     849774    25820    1502260001
     849774    25820    1502260016
     849774    25820    NULL
```

I will not get rows with `CodeTypeId = 854838` and `Zplid = 25820` because they have NULL only in the feature key.

I will not get rows with `CodeTypeId = 987431` and `Zplid = 26777` because they do not have NULL in the feature key .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic approach for this would be to
a) find the combinations of CodeTypeID and Zplid that have both a NULL and a non-NULL
b) report all rows for that combination of combinations of CodeTypeID and Zplid

For example

```
SELECT g.*
FROM   #gen g
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT CodeTypeId, Zplid
      FROM  #gen 
      GROUP BY CodeTypeId, Zplid
      HAVING COUNT(*) > COUNT(Zfeaturekey) 
          AND COUNT(Zfeaturekey) >= 1
    ) AS g_filtered 
        ON g.CodeTypeId = g_filtered.CodeTypeId 
        AND g.Zplid= g_filtered.Zplid
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1e9f503665fa5ebdfd159d1730ed2600)

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions. The idea is to count all the values per `codetyped` and to compare that to the count of non-`null` values. Then, we can use that information to ensure that there is at least one non-`null` value and one `null` value per group.

```
select *
from (
    select g.*,
        count(*) over(partition by codetypeid) cnt,
        count(zfeaturekey) over(partition by codetypeid) cnt_not_nulls
    from #gen g
) g
where cnt > cnt_not_nulls and cnt_not_nulls > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a CTE can make the code simpler and more intuitive：

```
with cte
as(SELECT CodeTypeId, Zplid
      FROM  #gen 
      GROUP BY CodeTypeId, Zplid)

SELECT g.* FROM   #gen g
JOIN cte c
ON g.CodeTypeId = g_filtered.CodeTypeId AND g.Zplid= g_filtered.Zplid
WHERE COUNT(c.*) > COUNT(c.Zfeaturekey) 
          AND COUNT(c.Zfeaturekey) >= 1
```